# Directory string formatting

Tags: python, string

I Have a folder that has a lot of subfolders and files that should be named in a certain order.

for example: Hello\bonj123\hi007\cIAo21.txt
root folder is hello and contains directories of the naming style:
a string, mix of string and int for the dir names and several extenstions for the files.

I Would like to run a code using python that can check this for me. any idea where should i start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for example:

```
import re

text = "Hello\bonj123\hi007\cIAo21.txt"
x = re.match("Hello\\[A-Za-z0-9]*\\[A-Za-z0-9]*\\[A-Za-z0-9]*.(txt|jpg)", text)
if not x:
    # No match
```

If you want to match with more detail you can do:

```
"Hello\\[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{3}\\[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3}\\[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}.(txt|jpg)"
```

If you do not want to have static file extensions you simply do

```
"Hello\\[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{3}\\[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3}\\[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{2}.[A-Za-z]*"
```

- * means unlimited repetitions
- {3} means the number of repetitions
- | is the or operator

You can use a regex tester like:
https://regex101.com/

And you can also look at the reference
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Your regex won’t work, you need to escape the backslashes twice (or use raw strings and escape them once). Even then the regex has errors (you only allow file names of length 1; you are searching instead of matching).

Comment: would i be able to specifiy the number of strings and integers in each ?
i can see that [A-Za-z0-9] means a mix of string and int but i want to specify the length of each

Comment: Updated the regex @Konrad Rudolph. Also added multiple extensions

Comment: Yes you can do this by using {number} instead of *. So for example for the string 'bonj123' you can use the pattern: "[a-z]{4}[0-9]{3}"